# Add a static block(widget) before the breadcrumbs

Tags: magento2, blocks, breadcrumbs

I'm using Magento 2.3.0, and I'm trying to add a block before the `breadcrumbs`, without any padding or margin.

I've created a block from the back-end, then my widget using this block, and then placed the widget on `Catalog Category`, as I want it only on category pages, and as container I picked `After Page Header`, but that places me the block/widget right after the `breadcrumbs`, and it also has the padding from the block class, that I don't want, I would like to have it 100% width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If default container not working for you, We have always option to add new one.
We can add a new container before breadcrumbs in following file

> mag2Root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <container name="before_bread" label="Before Breadcrumbs" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bread" before="breadcrumbs"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Above code will add new container after breadcrumbs.
You can select this container for widget container like:

[image]

**Note:** for padding/margin/width, you have a new class `bread` You can adjust as per requirement!